# Get unmatched records by comparing datatables in c#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I want to get the unmatched records by comparing two DataTables

eg :

Table 1

```
TransID   BookingID     BookingStatus   BookingType
1           11              Y               Paid
2           12              N               UnPaid
3           13              N               Paid
```

Table 1

```
TransID   BookingID     BookingStatus   BookingType
1           11              Y               Paid
2           12              Y               UnPaid
4           14              Y               Paid
```

I want to compare the above two table by using columns TransID and BookingID and I want the result as Below

[Unmatched Records]

```
TransID   BookingID     BookingStatus(Table 1)   BookingType(Table 1)   BookingStatus(Table 2)   BookingType(Table 2)

2           12              N                       UnPaid                      Y                   Unpaid
3           13              N                       Paid                        NA(NULL)            NA(NULL)
4           14              NA(NULL)                NA(NULL)                    Y                   Paid
```

How can I achive this by using LINQ ?????????

I tried comparing datatables by following method :

```
            var result = from dataRows1 in dtTable1.AsEnumerable()
                         join dataRows2 in dtTable2.AsEnumerable() on new { TransID = dataRows1["TransID"], BookingID = dataRows1["BookingID"] } equals new { TransID = dataRows2["TransID"], BookingID = dataRows2["BookingID"] } into rows
                         from row in rows.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[]
                            {
                            dataRows1["TransID"],
                            dataRows1["BookingID"],                       
                            dataRows1["BookingStatus"],
                            dataRows1["BookingType"],
                            row==null? "NA" : row["BookingType"]
                            }, false);

             //==== copy output of result into datatable named 'dtResult' =============================

            result.CopyToDataTable(); // This point records will be loaded in dtResult data table
```

This gives me only matched records .

Comment: Why don't you make inner join on TransId of both collection and then filter it based on unequality of the columns and then select in annonymous type

Comment: @teovankot I've updated my question, please check .

Answer (score 0):

The below code works and gives the result set you asked for. Couple of things though that I took liberties on
1. In your join condition, you only have the TransId and BookingId, but in your sample 'unmatched' data, it looks like you also want the booking status to be different, so I added that to my join - you can match whatever fields you want obviously.
2. Not sure what the scoop is with your select having an extra column after BookingType, seems redundant, but again, you can format the output however you need. 
But as far as the query, you basically need a full outer join, which Linq doesn't really support, but the below will give you the equivalent of two unioned outer joins, doing the same thing.

```
var result = (from d1 in dtTable1.AsEnumerable()
                      join d2 in dtTable2.AsEnumerable() on new { TransID = d1["TransID"], BookingID = d1["BookingID"], BookingStatus =d1["BookingStatus"] } equals new { TransID = d2["TransID"], BookingID = d2["BookingID"], BookingStatus =d2["BookingStatus"] } into leftJoin
                      from d2 in leftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      where d2 == null
                      select dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[]
                        {
                        d1["TransID"],
                        d1["BookingID"],                       
                        d1["BookingStatus"],
                        d1["BookingType"]

                        }, false)).Union(
                        from dt2 in dtTable2.AsEnumerable()
                        join dt1 in dtTable1.AsEnumerable() on new { TransID = dt2["TransID"], 
                        BookingID = dt2["BookingID"] } equals new { TransID = dt1["TransID"], BookingID = dt1["BookingID"] } into rightJoin
                        from dt1 in rightJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where dt1 == null
                        select dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[]
                        {
                        dt2["TransID"],
                        dt2["BookingID"],                       
                        dt2["BookingStatus"],
                        dt2["BookingType"]
                        }, false));

        result.CopyToDataTable();
```